# Mysql: Search database based on 'keyword' position

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have the following table, **tags**

```
+---------+------------------------------+
| tag_id  | tag_name                     |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 1       | test, subject                |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2       | subject, test, this          |
+----------------------------------------+
| 3       | how, is, subject, test, this |
+----------------------------------------+
| 4       | this, is, test, subject      |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 5       | test                         |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 6       | testing, microphone          |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 7       | microphone, this, is a, test |
+---------+------------------------------+
```

I would like to do a search for the keyword **`test`** and order the results by relevance according to the position the keyword is placed in the string in field **`tag_name`**.

So the order of results would be `5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 7`.

I've tried the code below, and it almost works, expect for the fact that LIKE 'test%' will return results that have the keyword **`test`** in the middle of the string in the **order of the unique ID** not the **position of the keyword** in the string

```
SELECT *
FROM tags
WHERE `tag_name` LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN `tag_name` LIKE 'test' THEN 1
    WHEN `tag_name` LIKE 'test%' THEN 2
    WHEN `tag_name` LIKE '%test' THEN 4
    ELSE 3
  END
```

The above code will return the following results:

```
+---------+------------------------------+
| tag_id  | tag_name                     |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 5       | test                         |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 1       | test, subject                |
+----------------------------------------+
| 6       | testing, microphone          |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 2       | subject, test, this          |
+----------------------------------------+
| 3       | how, is, subject, test, this |
+----------------------------------------+
| 4       | this, is, test, subject      |
+---------+------------------------------+
| 7       | microphone, this, is a, test |
+---------+------------------------------+
```

The order becomes `5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 7` instead of `5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7`

How do I return results based of the position of the keyword for LIKE 'test%', or is there a better way of achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) on `ORDER BY` too:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags
WHERE `tag_name` LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY CAST(`tag_name` LIKE 'test' AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
  CAST(`tag_name` LIKE '%test%' AS UNSIGNED) ASC,
  LOCATE('test', `tag_name`) ASC
```

You can debug the above query using this query. There you can see the `ORDER BY` values:

```
SELECT *,
  CAST(`tag_name` LIKE 'test' AS UNSIGNED) AS KeywordOnly,
  CAST(`tag_name` LIKE '%test%' AS UNSIGNED) AS KeywordExists,
  LOCATE('test', `tag_name`) AS KeywordPosition
FROM tags
WHERE `tag_name` LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY CAST(`tag_name` LIKE 'test' AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
  CAST(`tag_name` LIKE '%test%' AS UNSIGNED) ASC,
  LOCATE('test', `tag_name`) ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d7c6a894e38f4ee4811c1175796456f)